# How to use pretrained Word2Vec model in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, gensim, word2vec, word-embedding

I have a `Word2Vec` model which is trained in `Gensim`. How can I use it in `Tensorflow` for `Word Embeddings`. I don't want to train Embeddings from scratch in Tensorflow. Can someone tell me how to do it with some example code?

Answer (score 10):

Let's assume you have a dictionary and inverse_dict list, with index in list corresponding to most common words:

```
vocab = {'hello': 0, 'world': 2, 'neural':1, 'networks':3}
inv_dict = ['hello', 'neural', 'world', 'networks']
```

Notice how the inverse_dict index corresponds to the dictionary values. Now declare your embedding matrix and get the values:

```
vocab_size = len(inv_dict)
emb_size = 300 # or whatever the size of your embeddings
embeddings = np.zeroes((vocab_size, emb_size))

from gensim.models.keyedvectors import KeyedVectors                         
model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('embeddings_file', binary=True)

for k, v in vocab.items():
  embeddings[v] = model[k]
```

You've got your embeddings matrix. Good. Now let's assume you want to train on the sample: `x = ['hello', 'world']`. But this doesn't work for our neural net. We need to integerize:

```
x_train = []
for word in x:  
  x_train.append(vocab[word]) # integerize
x_train = np.array(x_train) # make into numpy array
```

Now we are good to go with embedding our samples on-the-fly

```
x_model = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None, input_size])
with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
  embedded_x = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, x_model)
```

Now `embedded_x` goes into your convolution or whatever. I am also assuming you are not retraining the embeddings, but simply using them. Hope that helps

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the line `embeddings[v] = model[k]` should be replaced with `embeddings[v] = model.word_vec(k)`

Comment: I also thought of this more manual approach (i.e. iterating the whole vocabulary and looking them up one by one using `model.word_vec(k)`. But is there a way to make use of `tf.nn.embedding_lookup`, which it seems would be more efficient? One post using Tensorflow with GloVe https://guillaumegenthial.github.io/sequence-tagging-with-tensorflow.html essentially produced a custom GloVe file which can be used to perform direct index-to-embeddings lookup. I wonder if one can do something similar with Word2Vec (binary) files.

Comment: @JIXiang in practice you get all the words you want from Word2Vec and save it in a numpy array, pickle, or whatever. Loading word2vec from Gensim every time is very expensive. `tf.nn.embedding_lookup` requires a matrix, so you can't use `model.word_vec(k)` on the fly. And `tf` is more efficient.