# Using phrases as input to a traning data

Tags: tensorflow, tflearn

I'm following the TFLearn - Quick Start tutorial with predictions for titanic.

In this dataset there is only one column with *string* value and it is converted to a boolean (0, 1) since tensorflow only handles numbers.

How can I adapt this model to a text classification so I can make prediction using a set where one column has phrases?

These phrases cannot be categorised (ie they are very different/free text and will be a important field for the classification task).

Should I instead add each word as a array? or each word as a columns in the csv dataset?

Comment: What do you mean by very different/free text?. They are not like normal occurring words like a dictionary?

Comment: @vijaym sorry if I was unclear. They are english common words. What I meant was that its a "description" field and not a group of 10 or 100 diferent types. So I cannot categorise that column, it is text where each prase only occurs once in the whole set.

Comment: As i understand, you want to convert those descriptions into number representation. In that case, you much look at `word-2-vec` representation. Its a representation of words where similar context words are assigned numbers (called embedings) close to each other. They are readily available as pre-trained models, ex, `glove` and `google's word-2-vec`  that you can use.

Comment: @vijaym ok, and in that case should I train my dataset before? or train each phrase before? maybe my question is: "how to process those texts so they can be consumed". I will investigate this, if you have a example nearby that can be applied in this example, would be very nice.

Comment: Use the `pretrained` model and for every word you will get a vector representation which you can use it for your classification task.This link may help:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43070656/how-to-use-pretrained-word2vec-model-in-tensorflow